ActiveMQ consumer from Apache Camel deletes selector
I'm trying to make a durable topic subscription using Apache Camel, Spring Boot, and ActiveMQ Classic, and everything works fine except the selector. If I place the selector at the endpoint the subscriber is created correctly, but if I remove it then it disappears from the ActiveMQ subscriber.
Is there a way to configure the endpoint in a way that doesn't deletes the selector from ActiveMQ?
from("activemq:topic:test_topic?durableSubscriptionName=sub_t&selector=color='red'")
.log("Message received: ${body}");

This is the code that works fine, but I need to remove the selector, like this:
from("activemq:topic:test_topic?durableSubscriptionName=sub_t")
.log("Message received: ${body}");


Why is it necessary to remove the selector? If everything works fine when it's defined why not just keep it that way? I imagine if Camel didn't behave this way then folks would complain that removing the selector wasn't effective. It seems to me that everything is working properly.

Because I'd like to make this selector dynamic only on ActiveMQ console, so anyone who connects to the subscriber is able to read the messages without knowing the specific selector.

What do you mean, "dynamic only on ActiveMQ console"? Why does it matter if someone knows what the specific selector is?

Any feedback here?
